# Git: Permission Denied when Opening Text Editor

Tags: git, macos, bash, permissions

I am trying to set the text editor that will open when Git needs me to type something (e.g., message for a commit).

I am on Mac OSX 10.9.5 and using bash.  I have configured the default editor to TextEdit - my .gitconfig file looks like this:

```
[user]
    name = My Name
    email = MyEmail@host.com
[core]
    autocrlf = input
    safecrlf = true
    editor = /Applications/TextEdit.app
```

However, Git will not allow me to open TextEdit:

```
MyMac:aDir user$ git commit
fatal: cannot exec '/Applications/TextEdit.app': Permission denied
error: unable to start editor '/Applications/TextEdit.app'
Please supply the message using either -m or -F option.
```

I also tried to move TextEdit into my user directory, but I can only move an alias (I think it's just a pointer to the original TextEdit location).  So, I get the same result.  But, it's just a problem with Git, because this works:

```
MyMac:aDir user$ open ~/Applications/TextEdit
```

How can I get Git to let the user (the ONLY user on this computer) open TextEdit?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### By having `editor = open -W -n` in your .gitconfig

Assuming Textedit is your default editor on Mac you need to specify `open -W -n` against editor in your .gitconfig

While doing git commit, the file will automatically open in Textedit

```
[user]
    name = My Name
    email = MyEmail@host.com
[core]
    autocrlf = input
    safecrlf = true
    editor = open -W -n
```

Comment: Did not work, unless I misunderstood.
MyMac:aDir user$ git commit
“open -W -n”: “open: command not found
error: There was a problem with the editor '“open -W -n”'.
Please supply the message using either -m or -F option.

Comment: you need to edit your `.gitconfig` with the above info (`open -W -n`). While committing use `git commit`

Comment: Yes.  The .gitcommit file is exactly as you specified, and it does not work.  It gives the error I show in my comment above.

Comment: For anyone else reading, this answer does not work and I am still searching.

Comment: OK, I got it.  You need to remove the quotes from the last line, so it is just 

editor = open -W -n

thank you